# React Material-UI Card Image Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-component

Having an issue displaying images. Looking at the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) and I don't know what I am missing.

I can't get the image component to show.

This is all from WhatsNew.js, I am calling an IG logo

```
import { ReactComponent as Instagram2 } from '../images/instagram2.svg'
```

Below I am also calling for a media file that is in the same folder but I get a non working image.

```html
<CardMedia
  image='../images/blog-post-01.png'
  style={{height: 140}} />
<CardContent>
```

Here is my live [link](https://wivio-testing.herokuapp.com) and this is the repo [GitHub](https://github.com/marcoantonio123456/wivo-testing)

Comment: where do you get the picture? local or server?

Comment: local, it's in `wivo-testing/src/images/blog-post-01.png`. The thing in the file where I am calling the files `WhatsNew.js` I am also making a instagram logo a `ReactComponent` and that file comes out fine. so why wouldn't the `../images/blog-post-01.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are doing now is right. Your image address/url is wrong. I tried this with a url of an image on the internet and it works.

```
<Card>
  <CardMedia
    image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
    style={{ height: 140 }}
  />
</Card>
```

Try this in the URL. It might work.

```
image="/static/images/blog-post-01.png"
```

OR import the image

```
import blog from '../images/blog-post-01.png';

<CardMedia
        image={blog}
        style={{ height: 140 }}
      />
```

Comment: I agree the image from a link works for me too. I shared that I am calling a `ReactComponent` in the same file that does work, so the path has to be good right? What am I missing?

Comment: I have updated the answer by looking at your other files in github repo

Answer (score 1):

the image to show must be given as object like this :

```
<CardMedia
  image={Instagram2 }
  style={{height: 140}} />
<CardContent>
```

Comment: That didn't even end up working. I just added the images to a public folder and called them as live links https://wivio-testing.herokuapp.com/blog-post-01.png

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and thank you for not giving me a negative rating